# MMFeederSource Usage

Tags: arcfm

I am trying to to write a custom feeder tracing routine, but facing some issues.
I am using the following ArcFM method:

*IMMFeederTracer.TraceFeeder(IGeometricNetwork, IMMFeederSource)*

*MMFeederSource* is simply initiated as *new MMFeederSourceClass();*.
There does not seem to be any QI from *IRow* and *IFeature* to set the source.

In the current form, the Feeder Manager starts but after a while throw an HResult 0x80044020 error.

Any ideas how to initialize the feeder source?
I could not find anything on the ArcFM Resource Center.

Thanks in advance
Ujjwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK...this is how it works.

```
IGeometricNetwork pGN = null;
IMMFeederSource MMFeederSrc = null;  
IMMEditFeederSource MMEditFeederSrc = null;  
IMMFeederTracer4 MMFeederTracer = null;

MMFeederSrc = new MMFeederSourceClass();  
MMEditFeederSrc = new MMFeederSourceClass();  
MMFeederTracer = new MMFeederTracerClass();  

MMEditFeederSrc.FeederID = FeederName;  
MMFeederSrc = (IMMFeederSource)MMEditFeederSrc;


//Trace the feeder  
MMFeederTracer.TraceFeeder(pGN, MMFeederSrc);
```